# Software for recording university lectures on Linux, similar to Sonocent Audio Note Taker

Tags: linux, audio, note-taking

There's a guy who's in my classes and he uses Sonocent's Audio Note Taker software to record all the lectures. The software is feature filled allowing you to take notes and signal a slide change so the audio, notes and slides are all synced up when you come to review it later.

The problem is that I like to run Linux and have for some time, but the software is only for Macs and Windows. Can anyone recommend software which is in any way similar to this which will be useful for university?

I'd try running the same under Wine, but I can't afford the £150. To be honest I'm shocked that it costs so much when it's aimed at students.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Sonocent seems to be really powerful, difficult to beat for little money. The only other thing I found (granted, not as loaded with features but might be of use, or at least, worth a try) is [cogi](https://cogi.com/). It can run in your browser (as well as on Android and iPhone), so theoretically you can run it on Linux. Have a look, maybe it is at least of some use.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the exact same thing.  I've got a colleague that uses One Note and it's quite handy.  I found Mic Note.  https://www.micnote.audio/  There is a free version, but I went for the pay version for $14.99 US.